# Run selected lines and show output using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I was previously using the Jupyter extension for VS-code (https://github.com/DonJayamanne/vscodeJupyter)  and could select my code and run it with the output being displayed in a 'Results' pane.

This no longer seems to work - when I for instance select a variable and run it the "Python 3 Kernel" status at the bottom flicks rapidly between busy/idle, but the variable is not displayed.

I see that the extension is now deprecated and instead one can run cells using the python extension, however is there any way to replicate this old functionality which was quite central to my workflow?

Comment: maybe you can use anaconda's jupyter notebook? even there you can put code into small blocks and run it, it usually opens an editor in your browser, if you don't want that, then you can use pip too, check out this link (https://jupyter.org/install).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So we actually just added this functionality to the Microsoft Python Extension and it just shipped last night. If you are in a .py document with #%% cells defined you can hit shift+enter in a cell with no text selected to run that cell in the Interactive Windows. If you are in a .py file with cells defined and you selected text and hit shift+enter then just that text (not the whole cell) will get sent to the Interactive Windows. If you are in a .py file without cells defined and you select text and hit shift-enter that text will get sent to the normal python terminal as before. But you will now see a one time pop-up asking if you would instead like to send shift-enter commands in non-cell files to the Interactive Window instead. If you miss the pop-up you can also just change the Send Selection to Interactive Window command that we had added in the options.

Comment: How do I achieve the same when working in a Jupyter notebook (.pynb), and not the interactive window? `shift + enter` executes the whole cell even when there is code selected in it.

Comment: Here I made a feature request to run selection in jupyter notebooks: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/200625 If you like it, please support by giving it a 